# Angular get swipe up coordinates

Tags: angularjs, touch, swipe, angular-touch

First see this example and try to swipe blue bar to left-right and up-down. Also check the console.log

http://bit.ly/1QfEOzY

I'm trying to design a media player with angular js. Minified view of the player is located at the bottom. There is play/pause button.

I want, if user holds on the blue bar, and swipes it to the top slowly blue bar will come the the fingers position.

I mean if user holds the bar and swipes middle of the screen, blue bars top will be placed users fingers position, when user swipes it to the most top blue bar will have a full screen view. Also, user can place the player to the bottom of the window by swiping it to down.

So, I need to coordinates of the swipe up-down action.

I'm able to read coordinates if user swipes left-right, Please try to swipe the blue bar to left-right and check console.log. Every thing is OK.
But when I try to swipe up it is cancelling.

How can I make it work? How can I get the swipe coordinate when user swipes it to the top of the screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution this is the best angular module for this kind of a job
https://github.com/lugovsky/angular-swipe-element